# Issue with counting newlines in Python

Tags: python

I'm having a slight problem with counting newlines. I'm working on a program that's supposed to count items from a .txt file (characters, upper/lowercase characters, etc.). However, my line counter is counting the amount of character plus one instead of the amount of new lines. For instance, instead of getting something like a character count of 1048 and a line count of 37, I get a character count of 1048 and a line count of 1049. I'm not sure where I messed up.

Below is the relevant code. I appreciate any assistance.

```
# initializing counters
char_count = 0
lower_count = 0
upper_count = 0
lines_count = 0
word_count = 0
prev_ch = ' '
is_prev_alnum = False



for ch in contents:
    char_count += 1
    if ch.islower():
        lower_count += 1
    if ch.isupper():
        upper_count += 1
    if ch == '\n':
        lines_count += 1


    # count words
    if ch.isalnum():
        if not is_prev_alnum:
            word_count += 1
        is_prev_alnum = True
    else:
        is_prev_alnum = False

    if prev_ch != '\n':
        lines_count += 1

    prev_ch = ch
```

Comment: You're checking `if prev_ch != '\n'`. I think you mean to check `if prev_ch == '\n'`. In other words, count a new line for every `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have

```
    if prev_ch != '\n':
        lines_count += 1
```

Since `prev_ch` is already defined as `' '` or a valid `ch` it is not `'\n'`, it keeps counting it for each loop just like the character

As suggested in the comments, you can just do `if prev_ch == '\n'`

Comment: Alright so quick question just for reference, how would I use the prev_ch to add a line to the line count if a .txt only has 1 line but no \n character at the end? Your suggestion works fine for everything else though.

Comment: In that case, lines_count value is 0 right? char_count is not zero, then you can assign lines_count = 1
At the end, may be add 
```if char_count != 0 and lines_count=0:
         lines_count = 1```